# How to make a Linux Application

Tags: programming

I am a new Programmer (Java, JavaScript and C).

I would like in the future to do / participate doing Ubuntu applications.

My question is; what programming language should I learn to become an Ubuntu programmer?

Comment: That question is pretty irrelevant. You can write C applications for Ubuntu, you can write Python applications for Ubuntu, you can write Java applications for Ubuntu, ... The list is long. I would say that almost any language has an interpreter or compiler that allows you to run it on Linux and Ubuntu. You should wonder instead what kind of applications you want to make and chose a language with respect to that. The platform is really not that important.

Comment: @Pablito Take a look at this https://makealinux.app/

Answer (score 2):

As you already know JavaScript (and HTML I assume) you might like "[Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/)" by Intel.

This is an open source project that will package your HTML as an Android, Windows, iOS or Linux (DEB) application.

[See the Linux documentation here](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/linux.html).

Comment: Sorry: -1: this should be asked on https://stackoverflow.com as it is a pure programming question.

Comment: @Fabby Hmm...  No, programming on Ubuntu / for Ubuntu is on-topic. Hence the bash and python questions here. It might be too broad, however...

Comment: OK, OK, removed delete votes and downvotes.  And now do me a favour and upvote the -1 answer here too because it's unfair that he should have a -1 where you just got a +1!  **:P**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a book by Jon Masters and Richard Blum [Professional Linux Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471776130).

- This book is broken into four primary sections addressing key topics that Linux programmers need to master: Linux nuts and bolts, the Linux kernel, the Linux desktop, and Linux for the Web
- Effective examples help get readers up to speed with building software on a Linux-based system while using the tools and utilities that contribute to streamlining the software development process
- Discusses using emulation and virtualization technologies for kernel development and application testing
- Includes useful insights aimed at helping readers understand how their applications code fits in with the rest of the software stack
- Examines cross-compilation, dynamic device insertion and removal, key Linux projects (such as Project Utopia), and the internationalization capabilities present in the GNOME desktop